# Writing a mixed matrix of integers and strings to .csv in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

Perhaps this question has been answered before but I can't seem to find any good documentation on it.  So my problem is the following:

Suppose I have two vectors of the same length in Matlab

```
x = [1;2;3];
and
y = ['A';'B';'C'];
```

Basically I would like to create the matrix `{x,y}` (ie 3 rows, 2 columns) and then write it to a .csv file.  So in the end I'd like to see a .csv file like

```
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

This is just a mocked-up example but really I have 75 columns with each being either a column of strings or numerics.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Actually here is the solution

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1

This works much simpler.

Comment: I edited my answer, only for sake of convenience. Make use of the solution you find the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort your data into a suitable `cell`

```
 A = cell(3,2);
 A{1,1} = 1;
 A{2,1} = 2;
 A{3,1} = 3;
 A{1,2} = 'A';
 A{2,2} = 'B';
 A{3,2} = 'C';
```

you may then call this function:

```
cell2csv(filename,A)

function cell2csv(filename,cellArray,delimiter)
% Writes cell array content into a *.csv file.
% 
% CELL2CSV(filename,cellArray,delimiter)
%
% filename      = Name of the file to save. [ i.e. 'text.csv' ]
% cellarray    = Name of the Cell Array where the data is in
% delimiter = seperating sign, normally:',' (default)
%
% by Sylvain Fiedler, KA, 2004
% modified by Rob Kohr, Rutgers, 2005 - changed to english and fixed delimiter
if nargin<3
    delimiter = ',';
end

datei = fopen(filename,'w');
for z=1:size(cellArray,1)
    for s=1:size(cellArray,2)

        var = eval(['cellArray{z,s}']);

        if size(var,1) == 0
            var = '';
        end

        if isnumeric(var) == 1
            var = num2str(var);
        end

        fprintf(datei,var);

        if s ~= size(cellArray,2)
            fprintf(datei,[delimiter]);
        end
    end
    fprintf(datei,'\n');
end
fclose(datei);
```